# SQL Query to pull name of hierarchy object, objects parent and parents parent via pk/ fk

Tags: sql, hierarchy, derived-table

Came across an issue that stumped me today and wanted to see if anyone had some insight.
Sorry for the bad formatting, not on here very much.
I have 2 tables Organization and personOrganization

Table 1 lists all Organizations in the system, columns are

| OrgPK | ParentOrgPK | OrgName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | Org 3 |
| 2 | 1 | Org 2 |
| 1 |  | Org 1 |

personOrganization are persons and the organization they work for, columns are

| OrgFK | PersonFK | isPrimary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 123 | 1 |

I’m trying to create a query that pulls the orgFK where isPrimary is 1 from the personOrganization table and runs it against the organization table and lists the OrgName of the parent and parents parent.

So something like this

| personFK | PrimaryOrgFK | PrimaryOrgName | ParentOrgName | ParentParenOrgName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 3 | Org 3 | Org 2 | Org 1 |

I want to point out that the PK and FK are not sequential as in my example above so I cant use something like OrgFK -1 =  Parent, the sequential numbers above are just to illustrate the example of child and parent organizations.

Or maybe a better approach would be to make a Derived Table of only the organization table that lists out all the Organizations AND the parents' names?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi - so what have you tried and what issue are you facing?

Comment: You can use this as a reference for the mark down table formatting https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support

Comment: What DBMS are you using? This is a classic example for where recursive queries are used.

Comment: Given there are only 3 levels, it’s probably not worth writing a recursive query, just join the table to itself the required number of times

Comment: Search for Adjacency List CTE

Comment: @Error_2646 Thank you for cleaning the formatting, I'll take a look at your reference!

Comment: @NickW Good point. If there are truly only three levels totally agree.

Comment: @NickW I'm currently trying out(as you suggested) the joining of the table to itself 3 times but I just felt that wasn't a very elegant solution when I first started on it before my post so I wanted to see if there was something else out there. Going to give it a shot and report back shortly!